# How to transpose rows into columns?

Tags: sql-server-2005

My database allows User Defined Fields(UDF) and during select, I want to combine the regular table fields with the UDFs in another table. Here is an example.

```
Table Person

Id  FirstName   LastName
1    John        Smith
2    Jim         Adams

Table UDF
PersonId  FieldName FieldValue
2      Age           28
2      Status    Available

Result of query
Id  FirstName  LastName Age   Status
1   John      Smith     NULL  NULL
2   Jim   Adams     28    Avalable
```

I am using SQL server 2008 and would like to see a sample using Pivot or UnPivot.

Thanks

Comment: Think long and hard before you implement this kind of design--for so very many reasons, it's just a bad idea. (Search on "MUCK" tables, good discussion here, though site requires free registration: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Advanced/lookuptablemadness/1464/)

Answer (score 3):

```
;With Person As
(
SELECT 1 AS Id, 'John' AS FirstName, 'Smith' AS LastName UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS Id, 'Jim' AS FirstName, 'Adams' AS LastName 
)
,
UDF AS
(
SELECT 2 PersonId, 'Age' FieldName, '28' FieldValue UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Status', 'Available'
)
SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Age, Status
FROM Person p
LEFT OUTER JOIN UDF ON p.Id = UDF.PersonId
PIVOT (MAX(FieldValue) FOR FieldName IN ([Age],[Status])) pvt
```

You could generate this string dynamically and use dynamic SQL if you do not know the columns required in advance.

Comment: Thanks Martin,Just to let you know the Person Table grows and contains more than the first two rows I stated in my question.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you would either hafe to know the columns before hand to use [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx)

Or you would have to create it dynamically

see

[T-SQL Dynamic Pivot Table Examples for SQL Server 2008](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-dynamic-pivot-table-example-code.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Astander, do I have other options besides Pivot to the solve the problem.